# How do I output a variable inside this span tag (which is inside JavaScript but HTML context)

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
function calculateDisplay () {
    var province = document.forms["calculateForm"]["province"].value;
...
...
document.getElementById("secondHeader").innerHTML = "Canada | " + province + " | 2017 Tables";

return false;
}
```

how do I format to display the variable province as color: black (usually that secondHeader id is lightgrey)

Thank you!

Comment: Put it inside a `<span>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if this is what you're looking for.

```js
function calculateDisplay() {
  var province = document.forms["calculateForm"]["province"].value;
  document.getElementById("secondHeader").innerHTML = "Canada | <span class=\"province-color\">" + province + "</span> | 2017 Tables";
  return false;
}

calculateDisplay();
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .province-color {
    color: #000;
  }
</style>
<span id="secondHeader" style="color:green;"></span>
<form id="calculateForm">
  <input type="text" name="province" value="Alberta" />
</form>
<button onClick="calculateDisplay();">Re-calc</button>
```